# Loop through SQL query using variable from another table

Tags: sql, sqlite, osquery

I have two tables file & users, I want to see the file info for each user for `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents`

So e.g. this would get the info from 'example' documents:

```
SELECT * 
FROM file 
WHERE path LIKE 'C:\Users\example\Documents\%%';
```

But the username is coming from the users

```
SELECT username FROM users;
```

returns

```
+--------------------+
| username           |
+--------------------+
| Administrator      |
| DefaultAccount     |
| example            |
| Guest              |
| WDAGUtilityAccount |
| SYSTEM             |
| LOCAL SERVICE      |
| NETWORK SERVICE    |
+--------------------+
```

Alternatively, there's:

```
SELECT directory FROM users;

+---------------------------------------------+
| directory                                   |
+---------------------------------------------+
|                                             |
|                                             |
| C:\Users\example                            |
|                                             |
|                                             |
| %systemroot%\system32\config\systemprofile  |
| %systemroot%\ServiceProfiles\LocalService   |
| %systemroot%\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

Which provides the first part of the path, but still can't get to join 'Documents' to end of query and also run the file query.

So, how do I loop through the each of the usernames.

I've tried modifying but neither table can be modified

Comment: How are these 2 tables related? Post sample data.

Comment: I have posted sample data, along with the queries that gets the data in the original post.

Comment: So the related columns for the 2 tables are path from table file and directory from table users?

Comment: Yep, I'd like to append Documents to each directory from users and then run the SELECT * FROM file WHERE path LIKE for the ''joined directory"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great opportunity to use a `JOIN` query:

```
SELECT f.*
FROM file f JOIN users u
WHERE f.path LIKE 'C:\Users\' || u.username || '\Documents\%%'
```

When you run this query, osquery will first generate the list of users, then substitute the username into the path provided to the `file` table.

`JOIN` is a really powerful way to combine the results of various tables, and it's well worth taking some time to experiment and learn how to use this power.

Answer (score 0):

Zach's answer is great, but there are times that a user's directory can be named differently than their respective username.

Thankfully, we also have the `directory` column in the `users` table which returns a user's home directory. Using this column will prevent directory/username mismatches from causing issues in your query output:

```sql
SELECT f.*
FROM file f JOIN users u
WHERE f.path LIKE u.directory || '\Documents\%%';
```